Hiding navigation bar in iOS 15 not working
Setup:
I want to hide the navigation bar everywhere in the app. I do navController.navigationBar.isHidden = true in my SceneDelegate and never "unhide" it anywhere in my code.
Problem:
I have code that runs perfectly on anything above iOS 15. However, whener I do navigationController.pushViewController(...) or navigationController.setViewControllers(...), on iOS 15 the navigation bar "unhides" itself, but only after the transition animation finishes, can I set it back to hidden.
So this works:
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }

but since when animating the navigation bar was shown, the view "snaps" back up to try to hide it again, since the view already did appear...
This doesn't work, the navigation bar is (and stays) visible:
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }

Like this it works, but once again, since during the animation the bar is visible, it has a weird "snap" when hiding the bar after the view is already shown:
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "background")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        }
    }

Lastly, when enabling swipe back gestures despite the bar being hidden, the bar instantly reappear
Question:
How can I change the navigationBar to always stay hidden? It would be fine if it would be hidden "app wide"...

So after figuring out that it was due to SwiftUI, specifically the UIHostingController, I found this post thanks to which I was able to solve the issue, by subclassing the UIHostingController and removing the reference to the navigationController, which it kept overwriting.
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

final public class CustomUIHostingController<Content>: UIHostingController<Content> where Content: View {
    public override var navigationController: UINavigationController? {
        nil
    }
}

Note: Be careful not to use the normal UIHostingController in other places, as somehow even using it in one place still didn't resolve the issue.

Awesome! Respect!!
